# How to add timestamp formatter in slick scala?

Tags: scala, slick

I am trying to convert long into timestamps in scala slick . It is working fine.

```
val longToTimeStamp = SimpleFunction.unary[Long, Timestamp]("to_timestamp")
```

But I need to apply the formatting like "`YYYY-mm-dd`" .

Is there any way to format the timestamp ?

Comment: How is the formatting relevant in this context? The `to_timestamp` operates on the types `Long` and `Timestamp`; formatting a timestamp as string is a separate concern. Maybe you could provide a complete code example?

Comment: Its converting the long into timestamp somethings like this `2016-07-13 11:18:59` but i only need `2016-07-13` .

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question; would it be possible to provide a complete code example?

Answer (score 0):

I have used a customMapper for DateTime in slick and then used jodaWrites from play.api.libs.json.JodaWrites for custom  formating. You can directly use Joda DateTimeFormater if you don't need a JsValue after formating.

```
    def updatedDate = column[DateTime]("CREATED_UPDATED_DATE")(dateTimeMapper)
```

Below is the CustomMapper for the above DateTime Column

```
      implicit val dateTimeMapper = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
        d => new Timestamp(d.getMillis),
        t => new DateTime(t.getTime)
       )
```

Now please find a formatter using jodawrites

```
    implicit val dateWrites = JodaWrites.jodaDateWrites("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a")

    implicit val catalogWrites = new Writes[UserCatalog] {
      override def writes(catalog: UserCatalog): JsValue = Json.obj(
      "user_id" -> catalog.userId,
      "catalog_created_date" -> catalog.updatedDate
      )
     }
```

Here for updatedDate the above formatter will be applied.